# How to change connection string after creating a setup project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I am creating a VB windows form applications , the working can be summarized as users fills some form and data is saved in sql server database.
Now the problem i am facing is that i have to deliver this as a setup file to someone, and that person will further distribute it to different users to run  on their PC, what i am thinking is that the code once installed on other computers and executed will give errors because of the connection string of sql server db as it will not match with that computer . I know that if a distribute projects i can put connection string in app.config and every user can change it according to his/her machine .But as i am giving a setup file how to solve this problem

Thank you

Comment: Should you not be using a single central database.  If you want to use a db on every users machine you could use sql compact.

Comment: different users are not in same place , once maybe in London other in Oxford etc..

Comment: Yep I'd go for a SQl Compact db.  Which is file based it sits locally in your application file structure so the connection would be the same for every app. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done through installer properties:

- create a custom dialog which retrieves the connection information from the user
- each control on that dialog can have an installer property which contains the control text
- these properties can be used for your connection instead of hard-coded values

If you need to write these property values in a config file, you can try using a custom action or another setup authoring tool. Visual Studio setup projects do not support XML file writing.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to access the name of the machine jus specify  Str_conn = " Data Source=" & My.Computer.Name & "; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=database_name;"...this will take each machines name properly for your connection string :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the setup file. It's possible to add a new screen and the user could insert the connection string himself.

It's also possible to add code at the end of the setup that could read a file (bundled with the setup) that can contain the connection string.

In all the cases, the c.s. should be in the app.config not directly in the application code.

Maybe this could help: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/446121/Adding-connection-String-During-Installation